# Unexpected token '}' in D:\ .users.ejs while compiling ejs If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:https://github.com/RyanZim/

Tags: node.js, express, syntax-error, ejs

This is my `controller` file

```
async function getUsers(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const users = await User.find();
        res.render('users', {
            users: users
        })
        res.render('users')

    } catch (err) {
        next(err)

    }
    // res.render('users')

}
```

this is my `users.ejs` file

```
<%- include('./partials/header.ejs'); %>
<div class="manageUser-container">
   <div id="title">
      <h2>Manage Users</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="new-message-container new-user">
      <a href="#" onclick="openModal()">+</a>
   </div>
   <div id="users-table">
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>Manage</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="users-table">
            -->
            <% users.forEach((user)=>{ %>
            <tr id="<%= user._id %>">
               <td class="name">
                  <% if( user.avatar){ %>
                  <img src="./uploads/avatars/<%= user.avatar  %>" />
                  <%=}else{  %>
                  <img src="./images/nophoto.png" alt="User" />
                  <%    } %>
                  <span><%= user.name %></span>
               </td>
               <td><%= user.email %></td>
               <td class="manage">
                  <img src="./images/trash.png" alt="Delete" />
               </td>
            </tr>
            -->
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            `enter code here`
            <% }) %>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
<%- include('./partials/addUserModal.ejs'); %>
</body>
</html>
```

and `error` show in browsers

> ```
> Unexpected token '}' in D:\programming\nodejs\chat_application\views\users.ejs while compiling
> ```
>
> ejs If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
> https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint Or, if you meant to create an
> async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}' in
> D:\programming\nodejs\chat_application\views\users.ejs while compiling
> ejs If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
> https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint Or, if you meant to create an
> async function, pass `async: true` as an option. at new Function
> () at Template.compile
> (D:\programming\nodejs\chat_application\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12)
> at Object.compile
> (D:\programming\nodejs\chat_application\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:396:16)
> at handleCache
> (D:\programming\nodejs\chat_application\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:233:18)
> at tryHandleCache
> (D:\programming\nodejs\chat_application\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:16)
> at View.exports.renderFile [as engine]
> (D:\programming\nodejs\chat_application\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
> at View.render
> (D:\programming\nodejs\chat_application\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
> at tryRender
> (D:\programming\nodejs\chat_application\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
> at Function.render
> (D:\programming\nodejs\chat_application\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
> at ServerResponse.render
> (D:\programming\nodejs\chat_application\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1017:7)

How can i solve this error.?

Comment: check in your `ejs` you might miss or add extra `}`

Comment: If i remove all the file inside the user.ejs then the  error occours again and again.  i can't solve this problem..  Also i create a new file  just html file then  again show this error but why?  i can't know how to remove cache data inside ejs.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you debug this issue, but you will have to resolve it yourself. Here are the steps:

1. We know from the error message that it is inside the `users.ejs`
2. And we also know that it has something to do with `}`
3. Computers never lie to us.

So this `users.ejs` has several partial views, or `include` directive. To narrow down the problem: Just remove all `include`, see if the problem persist? (restart the server if needed)

if the problem gone, we know that the error is inside one of those `include` files.

If not, we continue the step, by looking at any `}`, remove it line by line, restart the server (just to make sure we get the latest code), watch if the error gone, repeat.

Comment: already tryed use this procedure. but  didn't get any positive output.. If you  know how to remove cache from ejs file then  say . It will be helpfull for me.

Comment: Thank you man for share your knowledge.  I solved my problme use my debug knowledge..

Comment: I'm glad to hear you resolved the issue. Hope you can share the solution here and if you could, the way you resolve it, everyone will benefit from your sharing.

Comment: thanks man for inform me for shareing my solution.   and already post it....

Answer (score -1):

i created this error inside the users.ejs file

Here i declared = inside the ejs expression  like :

```
<%= }else{ %>
```

But the solution is

```
 <% } else { %>
```

i remove = sign after <% because else  is a condition  not  value if  i want to print some value then use <%= sign... i think it will help full for  many developer